# EclipseLink . Persistence Units anda Datasources

Tags: java, oracle, jpa, eclipselink

I'm finding differences in specifying the name of a datasource in a persistence unit or dynamically specifying it through a properties.

In the **Persistence Unit:**

```
<persistence-unit name="myPU" transaction-type="RESOURCE_LOCAL">
    <provider>org.eclipse.persistence.jpa.PersistenceProvider</provider>            
    <non-jta-data-source>datasourceName</non-jta-data-source>
```

**Dynamically:**

Using one of these properties
    props.put(PersistenceUnitProperties.CONNECTION_POOL_NON_JTA_DATA_SOURCE,"dataSourceName";
    props.put(PersistenceUnitProperties.NON_JTA_DATASOURCE,"datasourceName")

In the **first** one works well, in the second,
Using any of the properties (the correct looks CONNECTION_POOL_NON_JTA_DATA_SOURCE? ) :

```
Exception [EclipseLink-4021] (Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.3.1.v20111018-r10243): org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.DatabaseException
Exception Description: Unable to acquire a connection from driver [null], user [null] and URL [null].  Verify that you have set the expected driver class and URL.  Check your login, persistence.xml or sessions.xml resource.  The jdbc.driver property should be set to a class that is compatible with your database platform
```

**I want to have the DataSourceName outside the PersistenceUnit ..**..

Comment: It isn't clear, are you using PersistenceUnitProperties.NON_JTA_DATASOURCE and is it working? This property is "javax.persistence.nonJtaDataSource", and is how you would override the non-jta-data-source xml name. If this isn't working, what container are you in? JNDI lookup only takes effect if a J2EE container is specified. How are you specifying these properties?

Comment: Just works only with : PersistenceUnitProperties.NON_JTA_DATASOURCE , which value is:  javax.persistence.nonJtaDataSource

Comment: @Chris , works fine thank you. I was using the other constant: PersistenceUnitProperties.CONNECTION_POOL_NON_JTA_DATA_SOURCE  with value nonJtaDataSource  ...The correct way is to use : NON_JTA_DATASOURCE

Comment: CONNECTION_POOL_NON_JTA_DATA_SOURCE is a static string used to indicate which pool when using other properties as described  here https://www.eclipse.org/eclipselink/api/2.5/org/eclipse/persistence/config/PersistenceUnitProperties.html#CONNECTION_POOL

Comment: You are right Chris. Maybe is some confusing name... Anyway, the right way is to use PersistenceUnitProperties.NON_JTA_DATASOURCE which value is javax.persistence.nonJtaDataSource .   When is used  the Datasource inside de persistence unit file, works  with  <non-jta-data-source> property.